# Call method from instance

Tags: java, oop

Let's say I have two classes, `A` and `B`, in turn have some methods, `something()` and `nothing()` and an instance of `B` is created in `A`, as

```
public class A {

    public A() {
        B b = new B();
        b.nothing();
    }

    public void something() {
        ...
    }
}
```

A calling `b.nothing()` is all standard stuff, but is there any means which by instance `b` can call `a.something()`, assuming the instance of `A` is called `a`. If not, why is this *conceptually* wrong?

Comment: Why not try adding the code `new A().something()` to a method in `B`?  See if the compiler complains, or if you get any strange runtime behavior.

Comment: @RayToal - that's assuming something() is static. In this case it's not.

Comment: No, I did not make that assumption.  I know that `something()` is an instance method.  I think you misread my suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything *conceptually* wrong with this.

However, for the mechanics to work, `b` needs to know which instance of `A` to call `something()` on. For this, either `B`'s constructor, or its `nothing()` method, needs to take an `A` reference as an argument.

**example 1:**

```
public class B {
  public void nothing(A a) {
    ...
    a.something();
    ...
  }
}
```

**example 2:**

```
public class B {
  private final A a;
  public B(A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  public void nothing() {
    ...
    this.a.something();
    ...
  }
}
```

**example 3:**

There is a third way, applicable in some circumstances. If `B` is an inner class of `A`, it has an implicit reference to its associated instance of `A`.

```
public class A {
  public void something() { ... }
  public class B {
      public void nothing() {
        ...
        something();
        ...
      }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> ***is there any means which by instance b can call a.something()***

You can't get hold of *the caller* in a method so, **no**, there's no way to do that.

> ***If not, why is this conceptually wrong?***

Two issues come to my mind immediately:

- What would the *type* of the caller be? Since anyone could call `b.nothing()`, you can't assume more than that it's an `Object` which would result in lots of ugly down casts.
- The implementation of `b.nothing()` shouldn't *care* about who's calling him. What happens if you refactor `A` and move the call to `b.nothing()` to some other class? It would be quite surprising if `b.nothing()` all of a sudden stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The only way `b.nothing()` can call `a.something()` is if you tell the instance of `B` about the instance of `A`. For example:

```
b.nothing(this);
```

where B.nothing looks like:

```
public void nothing(A a)
{
    // Do other stuff
    a.something();
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass in `this` in the constructor to `B`, which would keep hold of the reference:

```
B b = new B(this);
b.nothing();
```

Note that letting `this` escape *during a constructor call* is generally a bad idea - you're letting `B.nothing()` call `A.something()` on an object which isn't fully initialized yet - its constructor hasn't finished executing. That can lead to undesirable and hard-to-diagnose behaviour sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, `b` would require a reference to `a`. There are two ways to provide that:

1. Pass such a reference in the constructor of `B` or give `B` an appropriate setter.
2. If `B` is an inner class of `A`, then it has such a reference implicitly.